# ElasticSearch UpdateByQuery using Index Aliases

Tags: elasticsearch

I am able to add a document to an index say `my-main-index` having some alias `my-alias-index`. When I did a search like below, I was able to get the documents.

```
GET /my-main-index/_search
{
  "query":{
    "match_all": {}
  }
}

or

GET /my-alias-index/_search
{
  "query":{
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

But when I try to do an update_by_query, none of the below is working. I am getting 200 response with no record is being updated.

```
POST /my-main-index/_update_by_query
{
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source['customers.company'] = params.company",
    "lang": "painless",
    "params": {
      "company": "apple"
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "customers.handle": "search-user815"
    }
  }
}

OR 

POST /my-alias-index/_update_by_query
{
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source['customers.company'] = params.company",
    "lang": "painless",
    "params": {
      "company": "apple"
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "customers.handle": "search-user815"
    }
  }
}
```

Could someone please help me identifying the issue?

Comment: Are you sure that `"customers.handle": "search-user815"` yields results? Can you do a search on that condition first, because with `match_all` is normal that you get results? What is the mapping of the `customers` object and `customers.handle` field?

Comment: No, "customers.handle": "search-user815" is also not yielding any results. Using customers.handle.keyword returns the results. I think I have to use this.

Comment: Yes, you first need to figure out the query on which to run your update and only then run the update

Answer (score 0):

Using `customers.handle.keyword` returns the results.